# Generating dynamic HTML page with UTF8 in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm generating HTML dynamically using Delphi strings (Delphi XE). What is the correct way to encode accentuated characters into my HTML?

```
var
 s : string;
 myHTML : string;

(...)
s:= 'programação';
 myHTML:= 
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'+#10+
'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">'+#10+
(...)
'<title>OmneeK Server - Intraweb</title>'+#10+
'<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'+#10+
(...)

myHTML:= myHTML + '<font color="red">' + s + '</font>';

(...)
```

with the above code I get (from the browser):

```
"programa��o"
```

I've tried with HTMLEncode but the result is the same. I'm using ICS components to handle the HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm generating a runtime string and returning the string as a response to a HTTP Server component (ICS). Is it possible to apply TEncoding into a string?

Yes.  A Delphi `String` is a `UnicodeString` in XE.  Delphi has had native support for UTF-8 encoded strings since D2009.

One thing you can do is simply assign the original `UnicodeString` to a `UTF8String` variable and let the RTL encode the Unicode data to UTF-8 for you, then you can send the raw bytes of the `UTF8String` to the client:

```
var 
  myHTML: string;  
  myHTMLUtf8: UTF8String; 

myHTML := ...
myHTMLUtf8 := myHTML;
// send myHTMLUtf8 as-is...
```

Another option is to send the UTF-8 data as a `TStream`.  You can place a `UTF8String` into a `TMemoryStream`:

```
var 
  myHTML: string;  
  myHTMLUtf8: UTF8String;
  strm: TMemoryStream;

myHTML := ...
myHTMLUtf8 := myHTML;

strm := TMemoryStream.Create;
strm.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(myHTMLUtf8)^, Length(myHTMLUtf8) * SizeOf(AnsiChar));
strm.Position := 0;
// send strm as-is...
strm.Free;
```

Or place the original `UnicodeString` into a `TStringStream` with `TEncoding.UTF8` applied to it:

```
var 
  myHTML: string;  
  strm: TStringStream;

myHTML := ...

strm := TStringStream.Create(myHTML, TEncoding.UTF8);
// send strm as-is...
strm.Free;
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is the cleanest approach to the problem. Regarding the ICS HTTPServer component, they provide a AnswerStream too, so the stream approach will work. The UTF8String won't unless you use a UTF8ToAnsiStr conversion and then the performance will suffer from the double conversion.

Comment: `UTF8ToAnsiStr()` would only make sense if the `HTTPServer` makes you assign an `AnsiString` for output. And in fact, in XE, `System.Utf8ToAnsi()` decodes a `UTF8String` back to a `UnicodeString`, so it would not be worth using a `UTF8String` at all, unless you use the `TStream` appraoch, or send the `UTF8String` bytes manually.

Comment: `TStringStream.Create(myHTML, TEncoding.UTF8);` does not generate BOM for me in Delphi 10 Seattle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Paul You are not doing anything wrong. It is not supposed to generate a BOM. And you are not supposed to include a BOM in your HTML anyway. The `<meta>` element inside the HTML, and a `Content-Type` header in an HTTP response, is what tells the browser that the HTML is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @Paul if you need a BOM (FYI, you don't), then you will have to use `TMemoryStream` instead and manually write a BOM to the stream before writing the HTML.

Comment: @Paul that is what *explicit* charset declarations are meant for.

Answer (score 4):

It seems which you are not saving the page in UTF-8 encoding

Try this sample

```
Var
  Page :  TStrings;
begin
  Page:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    Page.Add('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en">');
    Page.Add('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8" />');
    Page.Add('<title>Test</title>');
    Page.Add('<p>programação</p>');
    Page.Add('</html>');
    Page.SaveToFile(ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0),'.html'), TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    Page.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not saving the dynamic page into a file. I'm generating a runtime string and returning the string as a response to a HTTP Server component (ICS). Is it possible to apply TEncoding into a string?

Comment: Are you tried setting the content-type of the response to `text/html charset=UTF-8`? Also add these details and code (about `...returning the string as a response to a HTTP Server component`) to your  question to get better answers.

Comment: I am (as you can see above). I've found out that there is a function under HTTPUtil named HTMLEscape and this one does what I need. This function should work just like HTMLEncode (in HTTPApp unit) but it doesn't. Ive checked some comments and it seems that Embarcadero has left it behind. The official documentation has nothing about it. I don't know if this is the most efficient solution but the correct accentuation is now shown by the browser.

Comment: When I say `..try adding to the response the content-type text/html charset=UTF-8` I mean to the component which send the data (as part of the HTTP header) , anyway if the `HTMLEscape` function fix your issue post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Miguel E

I've discovered something interesting with Delphi XE4 / Indy 10 (probably applies to earlier versions too).  Could this lie at the root of your problem?

If you write to TIdHTTPResponseInfo.ContentType AFTER you have written to TIdHTTPResponseInfo.CharSet, then you lose what you wrote to TIdHTTPResponseInfo.CharSet!

In other words:(given Info:TIdHTTPResponseInfo)

```
  Info.ContentType := 'text/html';   // Warning!  Setting this AFTER setting CharSet changes CharSet back to ISO8859-1.
  Info.CharSet := 'UTF-8';           // So we MUST set CharSet last!
```

In fact, there is NOTHING else you have to do (other than write to Info.ContentText) in order to make UTF-8 encoding of (say) Chinese characters work.  You actually do not need to resort to using a stream.  Any Chinese (or other Unicode-dependent languages) written to an ordinary Delphi string will work when assigned to TIdHTTPResponseInfo.ContentText if the CharSet property has not been accidentally undone.

Comment: Shame it doesn't tell you this in the documentation

Comment: The Charset property did not exist yet when the documentation was last updated. There is a lot of newer functionality that is not documented yet.

Comment: Note that this `CharSet` issue has been fixed in the latest Indy SVN snapshot (in rev 5513). You can now set the `ContentType` and `CharSet` is either order you want, and the `CharSet` will be preserved if set first and `ContentType` does not specify a new charset.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to **save your file with UTF8** encoding.
For example, with a MyHTML variable as a TStringList

```
MyHTML.SaveToFile(HTMLFileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

It works for my application, with nothing more than a TStringList and this line of code.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm doing this without generating a file. Is it possible to include this encoding into a string?

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question I've found out that there are some issues with the HTMLEncode function (found in the HTTPApp unit), and that the HTMLEscape function (found in the HTTPUtil unit) does the same. The documentation doesn't say much but after retrying with the HTMEscape function the browser displayed the correct accentuation.

I don't know if there is a better way to solve this.

Comment: Reading all the answers, it's odd nobody points to the actual problem: in UTF8 (files, but also HTTP responses) the data _should_ start with a byte order mark. For UTF8 this is `#$EF#$BB#$BF`, but using `TStringStream.Create(myHTML, TEncoding.UTF8);` does that for you.

Comment: @Stijn Sanders: `TStringStream.Create(myHTML, TEncoding.UTF8);` does not generate BOM for me in Delphi 10 Seattle. What am I doing wrong?.

Comment: Apparently the encoding argument on the TStreamStream constructor is only used to get the 'bytes' of the initial data argument string. Take care to specify the encoding in your `SaveToFile` call!